# scam with blockchain

Tags: fraud

Recently a scammer contacted me to invest in Bitcoin. Well after losing my money with him, this person offered to return my money, and asked me to create a blockchain account. I did, then he asked me to share my id wallet and my password, because I did not know it. After a while he told me that my money was back, but it was not usable, if I wanted to have it. I thought it was strange, so I started to investigate, realizing it was a scam. I did not fall for his scam, but he still does not want to return my money.

My question is if I can get my money from the addresses that I leave, which by the way move a lot of money, it is possible to get the private key, hack those addresses, if they need the information I have the account still active.

The scams page is: https://kryptobinary.co.uk/

My non-spendable balance:

[image: Non-spendable balance]

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you were scammed.

The balance shown by your wallet software is not your money - it is that of someone else the scammed convinced you to "watch". Without access to the private key, there is nothing you can do. It isn't even necessarily the scammer's money either.