# Loading to Bitcoin wallets

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-atm

I've downloaded some bitcoin wallets because I am planning to load some amount in it using my ATM. But I don't know how. Will somebody help. How can I have some bitcoins in my wallet?

Answer (score 2):

### Firstly

Read

- [Help](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help)
- [I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/22796/13866)
- [How do you obtain bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91/13866)
- [Can bitcoins be traced to scammers](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/83197/13866)
- [scam with blockchain](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/80769/13866)

### Bitcoin "ATM"/BTM

Scrutinise "ATM" for fees etc to determine exactly how much BTC you will receive.

Open your wallet. Click the **Receive** button. Enter appropriate details (all aptional). Click the **Request Payment** button. Carefully write down or otherwise record the generated address. Details depend on exact wallet used.

Follow the "ATM" instructions and make sure you tell it to pay to the address generated by the wallet. You may need to type in the address or will be able to scan the QR-code.

### Fiat ATM

Use a service like "[local bitcoins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LocalBitcoins)" to find someone willing to swap your local currency for BTC.

Consider what you will do if the BTC don't show up for a few days (or never).

Meet them. See above re generated address. Give them your money and the generated bitcoin-address.

Hope they are honest.

### Either

Take a careful note of the **Transaction Id**

After the transaction, wait half an hour and see if your wallet shows the amount of BTC you expected. If not, check your wallet is synchronised and/or wait a couple of hours.

Try doing a web-search for "blockchain explorer" and type in either your receiving address or the Transaction Id.